# istio-1.7.2 installation, missing dashboards and pods?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-pod, sidecar, istio-kiali

I have installed istio using the official reference as on [Getting Started](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/) page.
Below are the commands i used:
`$ curl -L https://istio.io/downloadIstio | sh -`

`$ istioctl install --set profile=demo`

`$ kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled`

I ended up with below version of istio:

```
$ istioctl version
client version: 1.7.2
control plane version: 1.7.2
data plane version: 1.7.2 (2 proxies)
```

and my kubernetes version is:

```
$ kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.18.8
Server Version: v1.18.8
```

Every thing seems fine until i verify the objects installed in `istio-system` namespace

```
$ kubectl -n istio-system get all
NAME                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/istio-egressgateway-fbb7dc4f4-qzlxp     1/1     Running   0          84m
pod/istio-ingressgateway-5f84fcdd69-jnmqz   1/1     Running   0          84m
pod/istiod-77df9b78f8-r6n5t                 1/1     Running   0          86m

NAME                           TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                      AGE
service/istio-egressgateway    ClusterIP      10.111.110.194   <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP,15443/TCP                                                     84m
service/istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.97.41.146     <pending>     15021:30194/TCP,80:31161/TCP,443:32397/TCP,31400:31865/TCP,15443:30756/TCP   84m
service/istiod                 ClusterIP      10.107.118.172   <none>        15010/TCP,15012/TCP,443/TCP,15014/TCP,853/TCP                                86m

NAME                                   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/istio-egressgateway    1/1     1            1           84m
deployment.apps/istio-ingressgateway   1/1     1            1           84m
deployment.apps/istiod                 1/1     1            1           86m

NAME                                              DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/istio-egressgateway-fbb7dc4f4     1         1         1       84m
replicaset.apps/istio-ingressgateway-5f84fcdd69   1         1         1       84m
replicaset.apps/istiod-77df9b78f8                 1         1         1       86m
```

As, you can see there are few missing components -
There are few **pods missing istio-citadel, istio-pilot, istio-policy, istio-sidecar, istio-telemetry, istio-tracing etc.** These components were **available in 1.4.2.**
In 1.4.2 installation I could see **grafana, jaeger, kiali, prometheus, zipkin dashboards.** But these are now **missing**. Example:

```
istioctl dashboard zipkin
Error: no Zipkin pods found
```

Is this expected behaviour in 1.7.2 or is my installation broken. If the installation is broken, how else can i fix it. After all I followed the instruction from the Starter Guide.

Answer (score 3):

> As, you can see there are few missing components - There are few pods missing istio-citadel, istio-pilot, istio-policy, istio-sidecar, istio-telemetry, istio-tracing etc. These components were available in 1.4.2.

These components where merged with version 1.5 into one service named `istiod`. See: https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/istiod/

> In 1.4.2 installation I could see grafana, jaeger, kiali, prometheus, zipkin dashboards. But these are now missing.

These AddonComponents must be installed manually and are not part of `istioctl` since version 1.7. See: https://istio.io/latest/blog/2020/addon-rework/

So your installation is not broken. It's just a lot has changed since 1.4. I would suggest to go through the release announcements to read about all changes: https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/